# upload multiple images in android

Tags: php, android, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

this code can upload between 1-40 images, but no more than that, even when I tried to run the function several times.

Does anyone have an idea how to upload 100-300 images? even in several times.
Thanks

Android App Code

```
public void UploadToServer(final ArrayList<String> images, final String Name){
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        params.put("Count" ,images.size());
        params.put("Name" , Name);

        File[] arr = new File[images.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
            arr[i] = new File(images.get(i));

        try {
            params.put("images[]", arr);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        client.post("http://www.website.com/Ser.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                try {
                    Log.d("PHPmassage", new String(responseBody, "UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Failed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    $Name = $_POST["Name"];
    $dest="Images/" . $Name;

    if(!is_dir($dest))
        mkdir($dest);

    for ($i=0;$i<intval($_POST["Count"]);$i++)
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']["tmp_name"][$i], $dest . "/" . $_FILES['images']["name"][$i]);
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the issue. So anything between 1 to 40 images the server does get all of them, but starting from the 41th image it seems not to work?

Comment: He can upload a maximum of 40 images, not more than that, 
And sometimes he can't upload even half than that @YoniKeren

Comment: 'Sometimes' being a different device? How much connections are running then? In the end,background threads as well as connections are a limited resource-I am thinking that is the issue you are having. What are the error messages you are getting? Does your server get anything from the requests which are not being handles?..

Comment: Just one connection, usually it just stop uploading without any error @YoniKeren

Comment: Looks like problem with server configuration. There is limit with data You can send.

Comment: That's why I tried to send 10 pictures every time, but the upload still stopped @Michas

Comment: Do You send the same image (or the same set of images) every time?

Comment: No, Each time a different set @Michas

Comment: @Adi1231234 Try to send each time the same set of images in the same order. If it is a problem with server limits, you should get the constant number of successful uploads.